# How do I make an axios request to a local JSON file in my Vue project

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a JSON file in my Vue JS project, nested in the folder structure

```
src/assets/json/people.json
```

I'm trying to make an axios request to the json resource in my App.vue file

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      people: []
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.fetchPeople();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPeople: function() {
      let url = "./src/assets/json/people.json"
      axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
       this.people = JSON.parse(res);
      })
    }
  }
};
```

On my console, I'm getting the error below:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
  at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
  at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:59)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you that?

```
import people from "./src/assets/json/people.json"
```

would probably do the work.

Axios is an HTTP agent to fetch data from a remote server.
If the file is local, just import it.